# Creating custom keyboard for android

Tags: android, keyboard, android-custom-view, android-softkeyboard, android-input-method

Well, you might have seen few questions like asking for this.
But reading all of those questions/answers and almost all of the android inputmethod webpages in Google, I am still in trouble.

My final goal is to create a custom keyboard. But of course, mine will have special input methods for certain language.

But this time, all I want is to show my custom view when the keyboard is popped up. I've managed to pop the default layout based on a qwerty.xml file, which is something like this.

xml/qwerty.xml

```
<Keyboard xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:keyWidth="10%p"
android:horizontalGap="0px"
android:verticalGap="0px"
android:keyHeight="60dp"
>
<Row android:rowEdgeFlags="bottom">
    <Key android:codes="999" android:keyLabel="Settings" android:keyWidth="20%" android:keyEdgeFlags="left"/>
    <Key android:codes="44" android:keyLabel="," android:keyWidth="7%p"  />
    <Key android:codes="47" android:keyLabel="/" android:keyWidth="7%p" />
    <Key android:codes="32" android:keyLabel="SPACE" android:keyWidth="30%p" android:isRepeatable="true"/>
    <Key android:codes="-5" android:keyLabel="DEL" android:keyWidth="18%p" android:isRepeatable="true"/>
    <Key android:codes="-4" android:keyLabel="DONE" android:keyWidth="18%p" android:keyEdgeFlags="right"/>
</Row>
```

And in my class which extends InputMethodService, i have this code which creates input view.

```
private KeyboardView myKeyView;
private Keyboard keyboard;

@Override
public View onCreateInputView() {
    myKeyView = (KeyboardView)getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.keyboard, null);
    keyboard = new Keyboard(this, R.xml.qwerty);
    myKeyView.setKeyboard(keyboard);
    myKeyView.setOnKeyboardActionListener(this);
    return myKeyView;
}
```

and of course, because I had problems on applying my custom view to my source.
I just made some effort on the other side. When Settings key in xml is pressed,

```
<Key android:codes="999" android:keyLabel="Settings" android:keyWidth="20%" android:keyEdgeFlags="left"/>
```

it will call SettingsActivity

```
@Override
public void onKey(int primaryCode, int[] keyCodes) {
    if(primaryCode == 999) {
        openSettings();
    }
}

public void openSettings()
{
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, WRKeySettings.class);
    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

It works nicely until here, but I am in to this view problem.

What I think from reading android develpers and some of the articles is that, I could extend KeyboardView to make my custom view and in this method, I might be able to draw keys somehow with onDraw(). But I am having so much trouble on doing this.

Any suggestions will pleased. Thanks.

Comment: Just to understand the question clearly, you want to programatically create another layout? Do you want to make changes to an existing one? Do you want to reuse the same "keyboard" on different applications? You could "redraw" the keys, but they would have the same functionalities, or you could add views to your layout, and "redo" the window as well... Try to be as specific as possible on what you desire to accomplish

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To customize the keyboard you will need to modify your "qwerty" in the xml folder and the keyboard on the layout folder. I'll show some examples:

This goes on the layout folder

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<com.example.keyboard.MyKeyboardView
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/keyboard"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
android:keyPreviewLayout="@layout/preview"
android:keyBackground="@drawable/key_selector"
android:shadowRadius="0.0"
android:keyTextColor="#000000"
/>
```

And this goes on the xml folder:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Keyboard xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:keyWidth="10%p"
android:keyHeight="8%p">

<Row android:verticalGap="1%p"  android:horizontalGap="0.5%p" android:keyWidth="9.6%p">
    <Key android:codes="113"    android:keyLabel="q" />
    <Key android:codes="119"    android:keyLabel="w" />
    <Key android:codes="101"    android:keyLabel="e" />
    <Key android:codes="114"    android:keyLabel="r" />
    <Key android:codes="116"    android:keyLabel="t" />
    <Key android:codes="121"    android:keyLabel="y" />
    <Key android:codes="117"    android:keyLabel="u" />
    <Key android:codes="105"    android:keyLabel="i"  />
    <Key android:codes="111"    android:keyLabel="o"  />
    <Key android:codes="112"    android:keyLabel="p" />
</Row>
<Row android:verticalGap="1%p" android:horizontalGap="0.5%p" android:keyWidth="9.6%p">
    <Key android:codes="97"    android:keyLabel="a" android:keyEdgeFlags="left" android:horizontalGap="5%p" />
    <Key android:codes="115"    android:keyLabel="s" />
    <Key android:codes="100"    android:keyLabel="d" />
    <Key android:codes="102"    android:keyLabel="f" />
    <Key android:codes="103"    android:keyLabel="g" />
    <Key android:codes="104"    android:keyLabel="h" />
    <Key android:codes="106"    android:keyLabel="j" />
    <Key android:codes="107"    android:keyLabel="k" />
    <Key android:codes="108"    android:keyLabel="l" />
</Row>
<Row android:verticalGap="1%p"  android:horizontalGap="0.5%p" android:keyWidth="9.6%p">
    <Key android:codes="3"      android:keyIcon="@drawable/keyboard_shift_off_normal" 
         android:keyWidth="13.7%p"/>
    <Key android:codes="122"    android:keyLabel="z" android:horizontalGap="1%p"/>
    <Key android:codes="120"    android:keyLabel="x" />
    <Key android:codes="99"     android:keyLabel="c" />
    <Key android:codes="118"    android:keyLabel="v" />
    <Key android:codes="98"     android:keyLabel="b" />
    <Key android:codes="110"    android:keyLabel="n" />
    <Key android:codes="109"    android:keyLabel="m" />
    <Key android:codes="-5"     android:keyIcon="@drawable/sym_keyboard_delete_dim"
         android:keyWidth="13.7%p" 
        android:horizontalGap="1%p"/>
</Row>
<Row android:verticalGap="1%p"  android:horizontalGap="0.5%p" android:keyWidth="9.6%p">
    <Key android:codes="-16"    android:keyIcon="@drawable/keyboard_symbol"
         android:keyWidth="18.7%p"/>
    <Key android:codes="44"     android:keyLabel="," android:horizontalGap="1%p"/>
    <Key android:codes="32"     android:keyIcon="@drawable/sym_keyboard_feedback_space" android:keyWidth="40%p"/>
    <Key android:codes="46"     android:keyLabel="."/>
    <Key android:codes="-3"     android:keyIcon="@drawable/keyboard_go" 
         android:keyWidth="18.5%p" android:horizontalGap="1%p"/>
</Row>
</Keyboard>
```

Like you said, you can extend a class from keyboard layout, but it's more for customize keyboard events, like onTouch, onLongKeyPress,

Comment: Well unfortunatly, this is not the specific answer I'd want. I will just try to find a way to get this thing work and write a specific guide of this since there's like none about this at the moment.