# How to add action button in android keyboard view?

Tags: android, keyboard, ime

I want to add some buttons in my keyboard layout which will perform a particular method such as offensive words checker. Just wondering. Can i add some buttons inside **keyboard row key**? Do you have any other way?

Thanks in advance

Comment: You have to create a custom keyboard, for example http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38768096/creating-custom-keyboard-for-android or this https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7nsa7BuoWhU

Answer (score 1):

For the manual action buttons in Keyboard you should customize the android keyboard, the below url may helps you a lot

[Customize the Keyboard](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9577304/how-to-make-a-android-custom-keyboard)